# Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 freezes most of the time as I'm switching between work-spaces?

Tags: freeze, workspaces, workspace-switcher

It happened in 16.04 , I updated to 16.10 and problem still present .

I open terminal mode and I have to issue `pkill -9 compiz` to unfreeze it

what's weird is , it used to work fine , but now it crashes some of my running apps .

I make heave use of workplaces..

note : it doesn't freeze unless I'm switching between work-spaces .

#### edit

it doesn't freeze every-time I switch to a different work-space  , just sometimes .

Comment: Please see this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/815996)

Answer (score 2):

When mine freezes, I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. It unfreezes the workspace switcher. Try it.

Comment: It works for me with Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks for showing Super to trigger keyboard shortcuts!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar intermittent lock ups with 16.04 when switching tasks and have put it down to the built in graphics card on my servers. Matrox G200 with a whopping 32Mb of RAM. I have some new 512Mb cards on order which I am hoping will fix the problem. Could that be your problem too?

Comment: Please see this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/815996)